# How to translate TypeOrm syntax using QueryBuilder?

Tags: typeorm, query-builder

Sorting chats by nested relation

```
const arrayOfChats = await this.repository.find({
      where: {
        accountUuid: accountUuid,
      },
      order: {
          messages: {
             originalMessage: {
              time: "DESC"
             }
          }
      },
      skip: skip,
      take: limit
    })

const arrayOfChats = await this.repository.createQueryBuilder('chat')
      .where('chat.accountUuid = :accountUuid', { accountUuid: accountUuid })
      .innerJoin('chat.messages', 'message')
      .innerJoin('message.originalMessage', 'originalmessage')
      .distinctOn(['chat.uuid'])
      .orderBy('chat.uuid')
      .addOrderBy('originalmessage.time', 'ASC')
      .getRawMany()
```

It arbitrary truncates my rows and for example can delete row with the biggest time and as result sorting will go bad